# Espresso methods unresolved

Tags: android, android-espresso, ui-testing

I'm having some major difficulties getting Espresso to work with Android Studio.

I have the following code for a test:

```
import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;

import com.nullpointexecutioners.buzzfilms.activities.WelcomeActivity;

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ApplicationTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<WelcomeActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(WelcomeActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void testTitle() {
        onView(withText("Buzz Films")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the `onView`, `withText`, `matches`, and `isDisplayed()` all give me errors saying the methods can't be resolved. I can get it to work if I do a bunch of `static import` statements--but I didn't want to resort to that. (i.e. I'd have to write `Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withText(...)...`)

I'd like to think I have my `build.gradle` file correct--based on what information I could find regarding my issue.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nullpointexecutioners.buzzfilms"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 7
        versionName "2.0" //bump this up per milestone

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            zipAlignEnabled true
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            zipAlignEnabled false
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
        unitTests.all {
            // All the usual Gradle options.
            jvmArgs '-XX:MaxPermSize=256m'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.2.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:2.2.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test:runner:0.5') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.1'


    compile('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:4.6.4@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:iconics-core:2.5.5@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:2.2.0.1.original@aar'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.florent37:picassopalette:1.0.2@aar'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.channguyen:rsv:1.0.1'
}
```

Comment: You have to use static imports. That is standard practice.

Comment: @yogurtearl Even then it's not working.

Comment: Can you update the question to include the static imports?

Comment: Now it appears to work. Where have you read static imports are standard? I haven't found a thing about it. Every tutorial or article just has it working without many imports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need the static imports.

The official Google sample code uses static imports. Static imports are standard practice for fluent APIs.

[Sample Espresso Test](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing-templates/blob/master/AndroidTestingBlueprint/app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/android/testing/blueprint/ui/espresso/EspressoTest.java)

Answer (score 0):

For AndroidX:

```
import androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.onView
import androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText
import androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.isDisplayed
import androidx.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches
```

Check out the packages below to see what else is available:

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/matcher/ViewMatchers

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/assertion/ViewAssertions